# GPS Receiver Autonomous Integrity Monitoring (RAIM) - parity space method

Tags: navigation, gps

I am trying to understand RAIM. My teacher explained three RAIM methods, I will just quote all of them because I think that the jargon might not be consistent.

1. **Maximum separation / Position comparison method (PCM)**: Different combinations of satellites calculate the position of the receiver and these results are compared with statistical methods
2. **Pseudo-Range residual / Range comparison method (RCM)**: All satellites calculate one solution. The residuals of the pseudo ranges are then investigated with statistical methods.
3. **Parity space**: The teacher said that the system of equations of the satellites is transformed orthogonally with constraint equations. And these constraint equations are used to detect statistical inconsistencies.

My question: Could someone explain me in normal words what the parity space method does? If there is a simple/short mathematical explanation that would be great. Did I explain the first and second method correctly?

Comment: Good question, well-posed.  If you don't get an answer here and find out by researching elsewhere, I hope you'll post a self-answer - I'd be interested to learn about that parity space method.  I've only ever implemented the first two methods you listed; I think you explained them adequately.

Comment: @MrYouMath You may find this interesting: [Does GPS spoofing ever come from space? How are spoofings usually detected?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35249/12102)